# 99 Haskell Questions # 14

Tags: haskell, applicative

I had a question about one of the implementations of the duplicate function as described in 99 Haskell Questions (https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/14).

One of the solutions uses the list instance of Applicative. That particular solution is

```
duplicate = (<**> [id,id])
```

I was wondering why, when I tried to implement duplicate instead as

```
duplicate' = ([id,id] <*>)
```

I get

```
duplicate' [1,2,3] = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Instead of [1,1,2,2,3,3].

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
[f, g] <*> [x, y]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ h w | h <- [f, g], w <- [x, y] ]
```

Hence, we get

```
[ f x, f y, g x, g y ]
```

By comparison

```
[x, y] <**> [f, g]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ h w | w <- [x, y], h <- [f, g] ]
```

Hence, we get

```
[ f x, g x, f y, g y ]
```

The posted example follows similarly.

Remember that applicative combinators perform the effect of the first argument first. The "effect" here is, roughly, "drawing an element from the list".

Answer (score 1):

`f <*> v` isn't the same as `v <**> f`. We can check this with `Either`:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<*>),(<**>))

f :: Either String (a -> b)
f = Left "f evaluated first"

v :: Either String a
v = Left "v evaluated first"

showE :: Show a => Either a b -> String
showE (Left x)  = "Left: " ++ show x
showE (Right _) = "Right"

printE = putStrLn . showE

main = do
  printE (f <*>  v)
  printE (v <**> f)
```

Result:

```
Left: "f evaluated first"
Left: "v evaluated first"
```

Remember, `<*>` sequences actions.